# Update a Laravel Eloquent model twice

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I get 20 rows using Laravel Eloquent Model, with the following code, I want to mark them as locked after getting them and then mark them as unlocked after finish the work with them. But the article_unlock update to 0 is not being executed.

```
$articles_object = Article::where('article_posted', '=', 0)->where('article_lock', '=', 0)->take(20);
$articles_object->update(array('article_lock' => 1));
$articles = $articles_object->get();
foreach($articles as $article)
{
\\ do the work
}
$articles_object->update(array('article_lock' => 0));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you're reusing a builder object, not a data set.

Effectively what happens is your Builder (`$articles_object`) creates the basis of a query.

When you run the update method on this Builder object it creates and runs the query.

```
UPDATE `articles`
SET `article_lock` = 1
WHERE `article_posted` = 0
    AND `article_lock` = 0
LIMIT 20
```

This sets the lock flag to 1 on the 20 rows (because of `take()`)

The Builder object is still a Builder object even after you ran this query and has no concept of the rows it originally ran the update on. It's not a collection like you'd get from `get()`.

What this means is when you execute the second call to `update()` the exact same query as above runs.

The difference here is that your where clause is `WHERE article_lock = 0` meaning that it will never find the same rows as previously, because you've just set article_lock to 1 on them.

You'd need to keep track of the Ids you'd just locked, perhaps similarly to the below, and then run a query on those records specifically to zero your lock flag.

```
$lockedIds = [];

foreach($articles as $article)
{
\\ do the work

    $lockedIds[] = $article->id;
}

Articles::whereIn('id', $lockedIds)->update(['article_lock' => 0]);
```